# Conecting a controller's RJ45 port to laptop's USB port

Tags: usb, serial-port, rs232, rj-45, com

I have a CNC controller that uses RJ45 socket as a input for reciving instructions from my laptop. I use a USB to RS232 adapter and then RS232 to RJ45 adapter to finally connect my controller using a CAT6 cable. I need this many adapter as the controller is made to be used with COM ports and not Ethernet ports so I need USB to RS232. The controller works and my program for it also works (I checked on other controller that uses regular RS232 connector instead of RJ45 and I was able to communicate with it) but I cannot get a connection with my controler. I tried both null and straight wiring schemes, nothing seems to work. Any advice what should I do?

Comment: Too many adapters could be the cause of your detail. Also, shouldn't be way easier to use a USB to RJ45?. As far as i know, there's such [cable](https://www.startech.com/en-us/cables/icusbrollovr) that can accept RS232 protocol. Just throwing some ideas that might help.

Comment: You are conflating connectors with interfaces/protocols.  Associations/committees for HDMI, SATA, USB etc mandate that their connectors only be used exclusively for their protocol.  But generic connectors such as RJ-45 and DB-9, they can be used for any type of signal or protocol.  IOW if this *"CNC controller ... uses RJ45 socket"* and *"the controller is made to be used with COM ports"*, then that RJ-45 socket may be for RS-232 rather than Ethernet.

Comment: Explain what this *"RS232 to RJ45 adapter"* is/does.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need what is often called a console cable.  Like this one:  https://www.cablesandkits.com/mc/accessories/data-console-cables/console-cables/cabconusb/fam-334/fp-9900/

Or this one: https://www.staples.com/startech-6-usb-to-rj45-console-cable-black/product_IM16PB307

I suspect that they are all the same internals, just a different brand name slapped on them.

Serial RJ-45 ports are different than Ethernet ports and I suspect your "null" cable is actually a "crossover" cable.  In Ethernet connecting host to host uses a "crossover" cable.  With serial ports the equivalent is a "rollover" cable.  Like this: https://www.cablesandkits.com/mc/accessories/data-console-cables/dvi-vga-usb/datacables/rollover-console/fam-74/fp-719/

Why the cables are wired different is complicated.  All you need to know is that even though they both use RJ-45 the way the wires are run in the cable are different.  Both Ethernet and serial straight through cables are mapped one-to-one, which means an Ethernet cable can be used as a serial cable.  Using a straight through serial cable for Ethernet doesn't always work because Ethernet has more rigid requirements on signal loss and such.

If you want to clean up the mess of cables and adapters then I'd suggest trying a new USB to serial RJ-45 cable.  If you just want to get things working as cheap and easy as possible then I'd suggest trying a rollover cable.

I'm guessing on the solution here as I am not a user of CNC machines.  I have seen plenty of serial RJ-45 ports though, and they tend to be wired in only one of two ways.  One way uses a straight through cable and the other a rollover cable.  If you tried a straight cable, and an Ethernet crossover cable, and neither worked then try a rollover cable.